# Module object is not callable when using Glob

Tags: python-3.x, glob

I am trying to run some code where i use glob for importing the file but i get this error:

```
File "Model.py", line 46, in <module>
    input_logs = sorted(glob(train_features/log_features_0_20180815_000000000000.gz'))
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Not sure where exactly is the error?

Comment: Look the top of the file and change `import glob` to `from glob import glob`

Comment: Yes it works but i ran into some other issue :p